# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component - Environment / React- Three-Fiber

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-suspense

My App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Html, useProgress } from "@react-three/drei";

const Scene = React.lazy(() => import('./components/Scene.jsx'));


function Loader() {
  const { progress } = useProgress();
  return <Html center>{progress} % loaded</Html>
}

function App() {

 
  return (
    <div id="canvas">
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
         <Scene />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Scene.jsx

```
    function Scene() {
      <>
          <ambientLight intensity={0.2} />
          <directionalLight />
          <GizmoHelper
            alignment="bottom-right"
            margin={[80, 80]} 

          >
           <GizmoViewport
             axisColors={["red", "green", "blue"]}
             labelColor="black"
           />
        
          </GizmoHelper>
          <Text
            position={[-3, 0, 0]}
            anchorX="center"
            anchorY="middle"
            fontSize="1.5"
            outLineBlur="5"
            outlineColor="red"
            curveRadius="2.9"
            font="db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/02654c5f87934978cd2129477ad40869.ttf">
            
            Hello world
            <meshStandardMaterial
              color="#ec2d2d"
              opacity="1"
              roughness="0"
              metalness="0.3"
              normalMap={normalMap}
            />
          </Text>
          <OrbitControls />
          <Environment preset="city" background="true" />
        </>
      );
    }
```

My problem:

Every time I start the app the environment doesn't load and I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Loader`) while rendering a different component (`Environment`)
```

If I change the preset while the live server is running the environment updates and shows instantly.

I have already tried to write a function and render the environment only when the window is loaded but I still got the same error.

I have read somewhere I could use a setTimeout but not sure whether this the right approach.

If anyone could point me in the right direction.

Update:

I did not include the fact that I was using the GizmoHelper component.
Removing the GizmoHelper from the scene solved the problem.
I have added the GizmoHelper in above code in case someone else has the same problem.

Further Update:

I noticed the error is still logged in the console but now it does not affect the initial rendering of the environment anymore.
Might still cause an issue further down the road though.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution that removes the error :

Move your Loader component content to the parent like this :

```
function App() {

    const { progress } = useProgress();

    return (
        <div id="canvas">
            <Canvas>
                <Suspense fallback={<Html center>{progress} % loaded</Html>}>
                    <Scene />
                </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```